# Cordova: how to check if plugin is available at runtime?

Tags: javascript, cordova

How can the JavaScript part of a Cordova based application check if a certain plugin is available in the native part?

I tried to use

```
cordova.require( 'cordova/plugin_list' ).metadata
```

but it returns a list of the JavaScripts that have been loaded via `cordova_plugins.js`. Doing something like

```
if ( typeof( window.plugins.MyPlugin ) != 'undefined' )
```

doesn't help either - while the JavaScript part of my plugin is loaded, the native part might not be available.

What I basically need is a way to react to these errors (copied from an iOS project)

```
ERROR: Plugin 'MyPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "MyPlugin1093761140",
  "MyPlugin",
  "someAction",
  []
]
```

that ocurr when I try to do

```
cordova.exec( successFn, errorFn, 'MyPlugin', 'someAction', [{}] );
```

and `MyPlugin` is not included in the native project.

Comment: Can you share the code that's giving you this error? I understand that your question is about the generic case of handling this, but it would help to understand the problem more.

Comment: if you created the plugin correctly, you won't receive the "Plugin 'MyPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin", so there is nothing to check, start by fixing the plugin

Comment: You missed the point of my question. Stay ontopic please.

Comment: I need this too as the JS part of the plugin can be pushed into the App through CodePush but the native layer may be missing. Did you manage to solve this @Dennis? Thx - Note: I am trying to rely the on native existing methods and relying on their error when I execute cordova.exec with a timeout of a few ms.

Comment: This was almost 5 years ago - I can't remember. I stopped working with Cordova long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a plugin which retrieves the list of available plugins. Specifically, you could read the names of classes within the various `<feature>` tags in the `config.xml` which is packed within your project. On Android this can be found in the `xml` folder in the `res` folder where other resources are. Not sure about where it is on iOS at the moment.

Alternately, you could detect the error within the `errorFn`that you had in your example, since it'll be a string that says `"Class not found"`.

Either method is asynchronous however, so it won't be as nice as just checking globals.